AWS IVS whip&whep on server
does anyone know how to whip & whep AWS IVS real-time stage on behalf of server, instead of mobile or browser?
What I want to do: mobile publish to a stage, then server subscribes the audio from this stage, process it, and publish it to another IVS stage, the mobile subscribe the processed audio from the latter stage.
Based on the repos audio-only-example and amazon-ivs-stage-recorder, I have successfully published an audio to AWS IVS stage, but failed to subscribe it from the stage, which caused by 404 Not Found Error.
AWS IVS User Guide and API reference do not provide any information about the Restful API, or server-side examples about the signaling or connecting, from the two repos mentioned above, I guess the formats are:

https://xxx.global-bm.whip.live-video.net/publish/<participant_id>
https://xxx.global-bm.whip.live-video.net/subscribe/<participant_id>

I'm not sure if the two URLs are correct, any resources about the Restful API of AWS IVS will be great help to me.
Thanks advance for any help

Actually, the URLs are correct, the reason I can not subscribe from IVS stage is that: the participant id MUST BE the same as the publisher participant id
